# Using DNA to find biological father

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, 23andme

I have done both 23 & me and Ancestry trying to gets leads on who in the world my birth father could be. My mom truly can’t recall.

I found a first cousin or potential great aunt I think. She shares 931 cM with me, and I also found her ‘half cousin’ who shows up as a second cousin to me at 251 cM.

My ‘second cousins’ mother is half sister to my ‘first cousin or great aunts’ mother.  Their mother had each child out of a different marriage.

Who would that make my father in relation to them?

I’m so confused since they are ‘half’ cousins as well.

Comment: Has your mother been tested? The matches you found could be relatives on her side.

Comment: Yes my mother was tested and they don’t show up on her side of the family.

Comment: I think your father would be 1st cousin to the 2 half-sisters, and their mother would be his aunt, if I've sketched out the relationships correctly. Your 1st cousin / great-aunt match is more likely a great-aunt.

Comment: You could try the WATO tool to explore the possibilities in a more structured way: https://dnapainter.com/tools/wato